# Saved Draft Already Posted

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Tapping to ask a question gave me a message "You have a saved draft..." which upon loading showed me a question I'd recently edited (successfully).

Updated with before and after screenshot. The edit drafts seem to be stored in perpetuity, long after they've been made.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: can you scale that screenshot down a bit?

Comment: @Servy, scaled down. Sorry, it's really hard to do that from the phone itself

Comment: I repod this on my phone as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

There was a memory leak when the ask question form was created without a draft.  The form was staying in memory after posting/canceling, and the draft was resaved when you hit home.