# Handle back button customization in Chrome

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, google-chrome, ios-app

A nice feature to add: handle the back button customization in Chrome to be able to come back to Stackoverflow app after clicking on an external link.

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/ios-links

[image]
[image]

Comment: The SE app only lets you open in Chrome from questions and answers, not Careers 2.0 inbox items.  In these flows you do get the back button.  I suspect you have a jailbreak feature that lets arbitrary links open in Chrome and we aren't showing a back link for that.

Comment: A reasonable feature request would be for an option to open all links in Chrome.

Comment: @BrianNickel you're right for the jailbreak tweak and I agree about a new feature to add an "open all links in Chrome".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next build will have improved Chrome support, including the back button.

Comment: Is "the next build" 0.1.18? If so this seems to not work yet

Comment: @mhlester If your links aren't opening in Chrome, check the Settings app. The very first time you click a link it should ask, after that the option is tucked in there.

Comment: The login (google account) link opens in chrome (always has), but there was no back button to return to the SE app. am I misunderstanding what was supposed to happen?

Comment: @mhlester that flow is owned by a Google library separate from other links
 (mine opens G+), I'll look tomorrow to see if it can be added there.

Comment: well look at that. re-reading the original feature request it's plainly obvious that wasn't the request after all! sorry for bundling something unrelated into this. (it's unimportant anyway since if you successfully log in it switches back to SE anyway)

Comment: Was this every added? I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: @Zenox You can go into the Stack Exchange settings in Settings.app and turn on "Use Chrome (if installed)". If chrome is installed links should open there.